# mediaplayer seekTo() offset in bytes

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am looking to get the offset in bytes employed by the `seekto()` method of the `MediaPlayer` class.

I was wondering if there was anyway to retrieve this information directly somehow, and if not if there is away to calculate it myself for example:
If the media file has a registered bit rate in it's metadata, and I wanted to seek 10 seconds in I could use the following calculation:

```
10(secs)*(bit rate per second)/8
```

Can I assume that the `MediaPlayer` retrieves the bit rate information using the `MediaMetadataRetriever` class?

I have read the following:
[Accuracy of MediaPlayer.seekTo(int msecs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845161/accuracy-of-mediaplayer-seektoint-msecs/6908256#6908256)
And I am aware of the issues with variable bit rate, but I am not looking for accuracy in the `seekto()` method but rather how to get/calculate the value it uses for the offset to retrieve the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective of implementing `seekTo()` based on an offset is novel, but has multiple challenges attached to the same. Before going into the `seekTo()` implementation, some clarification about `MediaPlayer` and `MediaMetadataRetriever`. Both these classes employ an `MediaExtractor` object internally to retrieve the `metadata` information. Hence `MediaPlayer` *doesn't* include a `MediaMetadataRetriever` class.

First, let's consider extracting the bitrate. `MediaPlayer` is a generic implementation that should support multiple file-formats. Hence, for your design, you need to ensure that `bitrate` parameter is extracted by all file formats supported by your system like audio-visual formats such as `MP4`, `MPEG-2 TS`, `AVI`, `Matroska` etc or audio formats only like `WAV`, `MP3` etc. In the latest android implementation, I found that only `MP3Extractor` is exposing the bitrate through `kKeyBitrate` key.

Next, coming to your algorithm, I find the following challenges attached to a size based seek.

1. `audio` and `video` tracks are stored in an interleaved fashion. Hence, `time * bitrate (in bytes)` will not be directly helpful due to the interleaved nature of your input data.
2. Starting offset needs to be considered. In the file, there is some `metadata` or `boxes` stored at the starting of the file which is specific to the file format. You will have to consider this offset also which will be different for different formats.
3. If your input has more mnumber of tracks like `audio`, `video`, `text` or rather multiple `audio` tracks as in a movie, then the problem will become more complex.
4. Video frames are typically irregular in size. Even though a **constant bitrate model** is employed, the video frame sizes could vary significantly based on the type of frame. Typically, an `I-frame / IDR-Frame in H.264` can consume large number of bits as compared to `P-frame` or `B-frame`. This will pose practical difficulties for size based `seekTo()` implementation. One could easily observe a **1:5** ratio in terms of the frame sizes for I and P frames
5. There is a definite impact of the **variable bitrate model** which you have already acknowledged. Hence, I am skipping this point.

With the aforementioned points, without discouraging you, I feel a `size` based implementation looks to be difficult.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, I am still wondering if there is a way to retrieve this data from the mediaplayer itself. Consider a streaming over http case in which a seek is performed, i would assume a range request would be performed by the mediaplayer and that this data should be there.

Comment: When data is streamed over `http`, there is a cached implementation through `NuCachedSource2`. Hence, the `seekTo` will get triggered in the local page cache first. If the range is different, I feel that the request will still be based on time and not size.