# Android Frame by Frame video playback forward/backward and capture

Tags: video, android-videoview

I need help in playing the video frame by frame forward and backward in Android (something like a Slider.)
Is there a specific way or an API that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

The Android API doesn't support precise frame by frame seeking in the way you're probably imagining. There are a couple options that allow coarse seeking to and retrieving images from certain frames:

[MediaPlayer.seekTo(int msec)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)) allows seeking within the video but it's limited to key frames. See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845161/accuracy-of-mediaplayer-seektoint-msecs).

[MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(long timeUs, int option)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime(long)) can get bitmaps of frames, but again only at certain representative frames.

To get all the functionality mentioned you'll probably have to look at [FFmpeg](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg).