# How to get VideoView getcurrentPosition and set seekTo desire position not working properly?

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am working with one application that have multi language supported with same video. whenever I switch from English to Hindi or vice versa. It's set seekTo as per got current position But I am getting variation, it's not as I want from exact current position.

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

VideoView mVideoView;
Button btnHindi,btnEnglish;
int currenth = 0;
int currente = 0;

String videoPathEnglish = "/storage/sdcard1/test/english.mp4";
String videoPathHindi = "/storage/sdcard1/test/hindi.mp4";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btnHindi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHindi);
    btnEnglish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnglish);

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.my_Video_View);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(VideoActivity.this));

    btnHindi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
                mVideoView.pause();
            }

            currente = 0;

            currente = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
            Log.e("CurrentEnglish",currente+"");


            String videopath = videoPathHindi;
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videopath));
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.seekTo(currente);
            mVideoView.start();

            btnEnglish.setEnabled(true);
            btnHindi.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });


    btnEnglish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
                mVideoView.pause();
            }

            currenth = 0;

            currenth = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
            Log.e("CurrentHindi",currenth+"");

            String videopath = videoPathEnglish;
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videopath));
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.seekTo(currenth);
            mVideoView.start();

            btnEnglish.setEnabled(false);
            btnHindi.setEnabled(true);   

        }
    });
}
```

}

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: At which point does the video starts ?

Comment: In onCreate(), I have written code that is play video as english language default.

Answer (score 2):

When you seek to some position, you won't play exactly from position you want:

[Accuracy of MediaPlayer.seekTo(int msecs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845161/accuracy-of-mediaplayer-seektoint-msecs/6908256#6908256)